# Sub Report with a view type datasource returns empty when a parameter is passed

Tags: view, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report with few sub reports . i am passing an id to each sub reports as a parameter . So far, three of the four sub reports are fine. But one of them returns empty when ever a parameter is passed. All the sub reports used view type data source

The  sub report link between the main report and the sub report that fails is set as below
under the sub report section formulas.

```
{CONTACTNUMBERVIEW.debtorid} = {?Pm-JobSheetReport.id}
```

The {CONTACTNUMBERVIEW.debtorid} is a column in the subreport and the  {?Pm-JobSheetReport.id} is from the main report. It always returns null. However when i remove the parameter it returns record. I take the id to the view and it shows three records.

I am really confused, where did i go wrong? I did everything i could remember. Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the extent I see this `{CONTACTNUMBERVIEW.debtorid} = {?Pm-JobSheetReport.id}` linking is the problem... where it is returning `zero` records... try to link the correct field that produces records.

Edit:---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1. Check the query generated by the sub report and run it against the database to spot the issue that the report is generating.
2. Since you are able to see the data when adding the field to view perform the same operation on generated query so that you will get the idea on what to make change in crystal with respect to query.
3. Perform both operations that will solve the issue.

Comment: CONTACTNUMBERVIEW.debtorid =  the id from the main report. If i take the id to the view CONTACTNUMBERVIEW and add where debtorid= the id, it returns record. However it fails to return records from the crystal report

Comment: how are you linking tables in crystal reports?

Comment: When ii right-clicked thee sub report on the main report, there is an opton "Change Sub report links". I use that, navigate to the field i want to use as parameter from the main report and link it to the column debtorid of the sub report.

Comment: Thats where I guess you are going in wrong direction... I think you are linking fields that are not compatable..check at that context

Comment: I check sir, they are both of type number .

Comment: have you checked record selection formula? if not try to keep the same condition there.

Comment: Yes sir, the above condition exists only in the record selection formula. My confusion here is, the remaining three work. SO why not this? I check everything is fine. I verified the database is uptodate.

Comment: why don't you check the query generated by the sub report. go to `Database---> show sqlquery` and then run against the database this will give you the exact problem

Comment: Ok when i run the query, it returns null as well. However when i add the id to the view it returns records. I am confused but your method is very helpful though.

Comment: now add the id which you are adding to the view to the query generate and check the records in database

Comment: Oic . The column debtor id returns null when i execute the query. No wonder. But it returns value . I found the issue sir. Its from my view. I did something like , Select ContactNumber.*, debtor.id .... Then It does not return debtorid. Now i remove the * and returns only the columns need . Thank you very much wouldn't have figured out by now if not for you. You can edit your answer would select sir. thank u